# How is Bayes' theorm different from the theorem of conditional probability?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

The theorem of conditional  probability states that
$$P(A \mid B)=\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$$

Bayes' theorem on the other hand tells us the probability that a prior condition is true if a given event has taken place is

$$P(B \mid A)= \frac{P(B \cap A)}{P(A\mid B)P(B)+P(A\mid B^C)P(B^C),
}$$

However, what I'm unable to understand is why it's not simply not
$$\frac{P(B \cap A)}{P(A)}$$

Comment: [Bayes' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem) states that $\Pr(A \mid B) = \frac{\Pr(B \mid A)\Pr(A)}{\Pr(B)}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything you write is equivalent. Bayes' theorem can be proved as follows:
$$
P(B\mid A)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)}=\frac{P(A\mid B)P(B)}{P(A)},
$$
where in the second line we used that
$$
P(A\mid B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}\implies P(A\cap B)=P(A\mid B)P(B).
$$
For the expression you give for Bayes', it is just a rewriting with the law of total probability:
$$
P(A)=P(A\mid B)P(B)+P(A\mid B^C)P(B^C).
$$

Comment: Thanks! About the last line, yes, my bad, I got confused, I'll eddit it

Comment: done. sorry....